# How do I create symbol table of luaJIT-compiled code

Tags: perf, luajit

I want use linux-perf tools record lua stack, but don't spawn /tmp/per-{pid}.map file.

I build luajit lib from source code, and define Macro "LUAJIT_USE_PERFTOOLS"  in the /root/luajit-2.0/src/lj_trace.c. I reference this file and use perf record lua program, not create symbol table.

luajit-2.0/src/lj_trace.c reference.

```
#ifdef LUAJIT_USE_PERFTOOLS
/*
** Create symbol table of JIT-compiled code. For use with Linux perf tools.
** Example usage:
**   perf record -F 99 -e cycles luajit test.lua
**   perf report -s symbol
**   rm perf.data /tmp/perf-*.map
*/
#include <stdio.h>

My test.lua code.
function testlua()
    print("hello world!")
end

while(true)
do
   testlua()
end
```

Comment: I don't know the reason but changing the lua code to `for i=1,1000 do end`, creates `/tmp/perf-{pid}.map`

Comment: thank you! but I use for i=1,1000 do end, don't create /tmp/perf-{pid}.map